# When I adding permissions for users, Sharepoint is closing

Tags: sharepoint-designer, permissions, groups

I want to define permission for users, in Sharepoint 2013. I open Sharepoint site and then click "Add Users/Group".

[image]

I'm writing user's name. Then i'm clicking adress book button but sharepoint is closing.

Or I'm dont clicking adress book. Only I'm writing user's name and I'm choosing the group and OK. But sharepoint is closing.

Please help me. How I can I define permissions to users with another solve?

Thanks.

[image]

Comment: What do you mean by Sharepoint is closing? You are using sharepoint designer, so how what is closing after OK click?

Comment: Yes Sharepoint designer application is closing after OK click. It has stopped working. @Aanchal

Comment: Yes Sharepoint designer application is closing after OK click. It has stopped working. @Aanchal

Comment: CHeck if you getting any error on 15 hive logs.

Answer (score 0):

Go to site settings of your site, instead of sp designer.

Click user and group there and try to give permission there.

Comment: I tried to give permission in site settings. But I didn't see all of the groups here.
 Why sharepoint is off other status? I get this :
Problem signature:
  Problem Event Name: APPCRASH
  Application Name: SPDESIGN.EXE
  Application Version: 15.0.4615.1000
  Application Timestamp: 534ce051
  Fault Module Name: PEOPLE~1.DLL
  Fault Module Version: 15.0.4420.1017
  Fault Module Timestamp: 50673f1a
  Exception Code: c0000005
  Exception Offset: 000000000000bb14
  OS Version: 6.2.9200.2.0.0.272.7
  Locale ID: 1055

Additional information about the problem:
  LCID: 1033
  skulcid: 1055    @ateet